# Using a KendoGrid how to pop-up a "Successfully Saved" Message when doing a Batch Edit?

Tags: javascript, telerik, grid, kendo-ui

I'm using a KendoUI Grid to do in line batch editing. I'd like to display to the user a message upon successfully saving the changes. How do I do this?

My Mark-UP:

```
<div id="employeeGoalsGrid"></div>
```

My Javascript:

```
var goalsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: '/MVC/ResearcherPoints/GetEmployeeResearchers',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json'
        },
        update: {
            url: '/MVC/ResearcherPoints/UpdateEmployeeGoal',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json'
            //dataType: "jsonp"
        },
        parameterMap: function (options, type) {
            debugger;
            $.extend(options, { ID: options.id });
            return JSON.stringify(options);
        }
    },
    batch: false,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: 'ID',
            fields: {
                id: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                FirstName: { editable: false, nullable: true  },
                LastName: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                Title: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                TeamName: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                PointsGoal: { type: "number", nullable: true, validation: { required: false, min: 1 } }
            }
        }
    },
    sortable: true,
    filterable: true,
    columnMenu: true
});


$('#employeeGoalsGrid').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: goalsDataSource,
    navigatable: true,
    sortable: true,
    resizable: true,
    toolbar: ["save", "cancel"],
    columns: [
        { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name", width: 200},
        { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name", width: 200 },
        { field: "Title", title: "Title", width: 200 },
        { field: "TeamName", title: "Team", width: 200 },
        { field: "PointsGoal", title: "Goal", width: 200 }],
    editable: true,
    filterable: true,
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rodney, what about taking advantage of the complete event. It is bit dirty I agree, but I never managed to make Kendo success event work (not sure if anyone ever managed to - kendo ?).

```
 update: {
            url: '/MVC/ResearcherPoints/UpdateEmployeeGoal',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            complete: function (jqXhr, textStatus) {
                            if (textStatus == 'success') {
                                var result = jQuery.parseJSON(jqXhr.responseText);
                                // read your result   
                                // open your dialog
                            }
                    }
        },
```

Comment: This works except I'm doing a batch edit and the complete function get fired for each record updated. So I getting multiple dialog boxes popping up.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [sync](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#sync) event of the dataSource.

```
var goalsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    sync: function(e){
        alert('Synchronization has completed! Your changes are saved!')
    }
//...
```

Comment: sync is executed in async manner so you can't say if the operation succeeded. If you do it this way, you can't base your alert at the data what returned.

Comment: The sync event is not firing for me when I click the save to update. I added a debugger; statement is it never get called.

Comment: Not sure, does the error event of the dataSource get triggered?