# Timing issue: count being overwritten by results

Tags: ajax, datasource, kendo-ui

I've pretty much stared myself blind on this issue: I'm using KendoUI's dataSource and some filters to do a sort of ajax-search: http://www.high-quality.nl/kandidaten/vacatures/. What happens is that my functions aren't being executed in proper order. My dataSource and an kendoObservable look like this:

```
var jobTemplate = kendo.template($('#job-stub').html());
var jobCount = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
    count: 20
});

jobCount.bind('change', function(){
    if(this.count == 0){
        $('#result-wrapper').prepend('<h2>Er zijn geen vacatures gevonden.</h2>');
    } else if(this.count == 1){
        $('#result-wrapper').prepend('<h2>Er is <span class="blue">'+this.count+'</span> vacature gevonden.</h2>');
    } else {
        $('#result-wrapper').prepend('<h2>Er zijn <span class="blue">'+this.count+'</span> vacatures gevonden.</h2>');
    }
});

var jobData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: '/jobs/json/search',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                job_matching_function: function(){
                    return $('#job_matching_function').val();
                },
                job_matching_type: function(){
                    return $('#job_matching_type').val();
                },
                job_matching_hours: function(){
                    return $('#job_matching_hours').val();
                },
                job_matching_education: function(){
                    return $('#job_matching_education').val();
                }
            }
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: 'results'
    },
    change: function(){
        $('#result-wrapper').html(kendo.render(jobTemplate, this.view()));
        jobCount.set('count', this.view().length);
    }
});
```

and when one of the filters get clicked I run `jobData.read();`. Every now and then the result-count won't get appear. Does anyone have any idea why?

Thanks,

- Steven

Answer (score 1):

Steven, I never tried having 4 anonymous methods in the read, not sure how it behaves - try to have one read call with one return. Then you can use complete event as its shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569676/using-a-kendogrid-how-to-pop-up-a-successfully-saved-message-when-doing-a-batc).